# background in CSSStyleDeclaration is undefined in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css

I have a small function that will take a string of css (eg `background: red; width: 145px; height: 145px;`)
and return a `CSSStyleDeclaration` but if I have a `background` property (and `background-color` etc) the`CSSStyleDeclaration` will have `background-color` etc set as `undefined` in Firefox.

```
_parseCSS: function(css) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<div style="' + css + '"></div>';
  return div.childNodes[0].style
}
```

does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** here's the code that doesn't work with Firefox:

```
style: function(style) {
    var css = this._parseCSS(style);
    return this.each(this._elem, function(element) {
      this.each(css, function(s) {
        var prop = s;
        element.style[prop] = css[s];
      });
    });
  },
```

the parameter `style` is the string of css.

Comment: Works for me in Firefox 3.6.9 (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U4DFA/)). What's your browser version?

Comment: you missed a semicolon after style , but that shouldn't break anything.

Comment: Post code which returns 'undefined' value.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 3.6.12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because hyphenated style attributes are not the same in javascript meaning, `background-color` is `backgroundColor` in javascript. So,`element.style.background-color` should be `element.style.backgroundColor`.